# new arrived 7.5V tablet battery only measured 7.05V, is it a bad battery?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, laptop

I am replacing my Surface Pro 4 battery. I bought a new replacement battery on eBay. Its spec is 38.2Wh 7.5V = 5087mAh. I measured with my multimeter today. It shows 7.05V. I noticed that one of the YouTubers' replacement battery is 7.67V before he install it. I am wondering the 7.05V is because it is a bad battery or because it is a new battery that may not be fully charged?

Comment: It has 2 cells. What is the voltage on each cell?

Comment: It should be supplied a bit below half charge (to avoid chemical degradation) but nowhere near completely empty. If both cells have similar voltage, 3.5V, it sounds fine to me. Charge before use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you buy it, a new Lithium Ion (LiIon) or Lithium Polymer (LiPo) battery  *should* not be fully charged.

Keeping LiIon/LiPo batteries fully charged stesses (and damages) the battery and makes it lose useful capacity when stored for a long time (for example when stored in a warehouse between production and distribution to the customer).

Keeping a LiIon/LiPo battery charged around 40-60% of its full capacity (such as the charge your replacement battery came with) will make it deteriorate much slower.

When you buy a new LiIon/LiPo battery, it will usually be only half charged because of this reason.

Batteries will also slowly discharge by themselves over time (self discharge). When left too long without a recharge, they will be completely empty which will also irreversibly damage the battery.

Answer (score 2):

Lithium batteries discharge by themselves as they sit on a shelf.  You cannot make a determination whether a battery is good or bad by its current state of charge.